# Custom card component not responsive when text and icon aligned on the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made my own custom card component to learn CSS and HTML from scratch.

This is my code for HTML:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div>
        <div class="search-event-block">
            <div class="search-event-icon-left">
                <i class="icon-horse search-event-icon-left-size"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="search-event-block-inner">
                <div class="search-event-block-title">
                    <label class="search-event-block-padding ">Title</label>
                </div>
                <div class="search-event-block-subtitle">
                    <label class="search-event-block-padding">Subtitle<i class="icon-basket search-event-icon-right-size"></i></label>
                </div>
                <div class="search-event-block-links ">
                    <label class="search-event-block-padding">Go block | Delete block</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my code for css styling for the card component:

```
.search-event-block {
        height: 87px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #fff;        
    }

       .search-event-block-inner {
        position: relative;
        top: -87px;
        left: 74px;
        width: calc(100% - 74px);
    }

    .search-event-block-inner {
        position: relative;
        top: -87px;
        left: 74px;
        width: calc(100% - 74px);
    }

    .search-event-block-title {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 11px;
    }

    .search-event-block-subtitle {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }

    .search-event-block-links {
        color: #2E85DE;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-top: 6px;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }

    .search-event-icon-left {
        background-color: #F2F3F7;
        height: 87px;
        width: 74px;
        padding-top: 18px;
        padding-left: 13px;
    }

     .search-event-icon-right {      
        font-size: 18px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .search-event-icon-left-size {
        font-size: 33px;
        color: #214A96;
    }

    .search-event-icon-right-size {
        font-size: 21px;
        color: #1B4593;
        padding-left: 84px;
    }

    .search-event-block-padding {
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

The problem is in the class: `search-event-block-subtitle`. I want the subtitle and the icon on the same line. The icon must align to the end of the card. This is working fine, but when I resize the window the icon goes **under** the subtitle. When the screen goes smaller I want that the icon still remains on the same line as the subtitle.

I used bootstrap only for the cols and rows. I have tried to something like this:

```
<div class="row">
//col6
label
//col6
icon
</div>
```

This didn't work for me

How can I align the **subtitle** and **icon** on the same line when the screen goes smaller?

I also have problems with the height it doesn't auto scale. How can I fix this problem?

I have made a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ptyagcdq/1/

Comment: You deleted your latest question. I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/x4yap62b/) for it. As you can see, the issue doesn't appear to be happening. Consider undeleting it and adding relevant info, if you still need help. Or was it about the `.table` bottom margin which I removed using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to update your subtitle layer to this:

```
<div class="search-event-block-subtitle">
    <label class="search-event-block-padding">Subtitle</label>
    <i class="icon-basket search-event-icon-right-size"></i>
</div>
```

This will keep the subtitle text separate from the icon and will give you better control over it. Then in your css add this class:

```
.search-event-block-subtitle label {
    width: calc(100% - 84px);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And update the "search-event-icon-right-size" class to:

```
.search-event-icon-right-size {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #1B4593;
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The width calculation in your search-event-block-subtitle label is 100% - 84px because you should subtract the icon's width and the search-event-block-subtitle label padding. You should adjust these numbers to the actual size of the icon you are going to use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time this is working well! Problem is now when the icon scaled the **links** goes outside the box. Is there a way to set the `height` on **auto**?

Comment: In your .search-event-block class you set the height to 87px. You can either remove that, change it to min-height: 87px or set overflow-y: auto. Also if the answer replies to your initial question please accept it.